# Unable to debug on the PHP Server Side from my Android App

Tags: php, android, eclipse, xdebug

Have a Andriod app that calls a php web service using KSOAP2. The Php WebService uses nuSOAP to receive requests and send response back to the app. -

After lot of struggle was finally able to install xDebug for eclipse and get it working. What I mean by that is - I select the php file and choose "Debug As" , the IDE (Eclipse) goes into Debug perspective - So far so good.

The issues what I ran into is this. From the Andriod app when a call is made to the webservice (Line 3) it does not put my php page into debug perspective for me to walk through. What am I missing? Before running the Andriod app in debug mode, I made sure that I ran the php page in debug page with a break point at the first line. Any assistance/guidance would be very much appreciated.

```
//this is the actual part that will call the webservice
1. HttpTransportSE client = new HttpTransportSE(webServiceURL);
2. SOAP_ACTION = getNAMESPACE()+getMETHODNAME();
3. client.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okies, For those on the look out for an answer:

Typically Xdebug is set up to initiate debugging if specified in the request. Your app is doing the request so it won't trigger.
Set xdebug.remote_autostart=1 to skip that requirement.

http://forums.devshed.com/php-development-5/unable-debug-server-andriod-app-962693.html